# Linked list not working properly?

Tags: python

This is supposed to be a linked list which is gets a new node every time a line from a file runs through the loop. This is only a part of my code, but everything else works fine, so I didn't think it was relevant to include all of it.

The problem I'm having is that the nodes aren't being added properly. If I put print(head) and print(head['next']) immediately after this, it prints the correct information for the head node, but for head['next'] it prints "None", even when enough lines have run through the program for head['next'] to have data in it.

I followed instructions that I found for creating a linked list, but I must have done something wrong. I'm just not sure what it is.

```
if data[0] == "submit":
    node = {}
    node['data'] = data
    head = node
    head['next'] = None
    if len(data) > 1:
        if data[1] > "101":
            newNode = {}
            newNode = head['next']
```

Comment: Why should data be `>"101"`? YOu know this is string comparison?

Comment: So, why not just use the  built-in `list` or `collections.deque` if you want linked-list performance characteristics?

Comment: I think they might be learning about how a LL is implemented.

Comment: If you are happy with an answer, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you wrote:

```
newNode = head['next']
```

on the last line, and it should be:

```
head['next'] = newNode
```

So that the `head` dictionary links to the `newNode`.

Furthermore the `data[1] > "101"` is suspicious, since it will perform *lexicographical comparison*, instead of a numerical one.

You can probably rewrite your script to:

```
if data[0] == "submit":
    # why do you assign the entire list as 'data'?
    node = {'data': data, 'next': None}
    head = node
    if len(data) > 1 and int(data[1]) > 101:  # numerical comparison?
        newNode = {}
        head['next'] = newNode
        newNode['data'] = data[1]  # assign second element?
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing more of your code, you forgot to assign the old head to this new node

```
node = {}
node["data"] = data # Sets data.
node["next"] = None # sets the next to none because there is no next as the head.
head["next"] = node # set the current heads next variable to this new node.
head = head["next"] # shift head to the new node by doing this.
```

Im a fan of more Object oriented code though, and while there is a war between Object oriented code vs scripts, this is a good spot to define classes etc and just make it more clean as you are already creating objects and assigning static keys.

Here is a simple class i put together:

```
class Node:
    __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    set_next(self, node):
        self.next = node

class LL:
    __init__(self):
        self.start = None
        self.end = None
        self.current = None


    appendNode(self, node):
        self.end.set_next(node)
        self.end = self.end.next


    appendData(self, data):
        self.appendNode(new Node(data))

    walk_list(self):
        self.current = self.start
        while self.current is not None:
            yield self.current
            self.current = self.current.next
```